# Clicking on a parent element

Tags: jquery, tree-traversal

I'm having lots of trouble with `elrte.min.js`. If I have a page like:

```
<div id="#main">
<div class="el-rte">
<ul><li id="thisistheelement"></li></ul>
</div>
<span class="edit_submit"></span>
</div>
```

if '**this**' is `#thisisthelement`, could I trigger a click on `.edit_submit` by running following jQuery?

```
this.parents(".el-rte").siblings(".edit_submit").trigger('click');
```

Yes I know it's not a very pretty method, but I can't figure out how to do this action otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

```
<span class=".edit_submit"></span>
```

update to:

```
<span class="edit_submit"></span>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not actually how it is within the production code.

Comment: If not this question.  "'this' is #thisisthelement" context? And their surroundings? code too little.